# Nginx: proxy_pass path of domain to different web server

Tags: nginx, laravel

We plan to upgrade our web application from php native based application to PHP Framework based (Laravel) to enhance application security and performance. My task is to split traffic where every request pointed to domain `app.localhost` without postfix `/v3` still forwarded to old application on `php-native` web server node, and proxy all request with `/v3` path to `laravel` web server node. Below is my configuration that resulting all asset (css and js) and URL generated by Laravel pointed to root path.

[Laravel generated URL pointed to old application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GdOV.png)

### Front Proxy (Public Network)

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  app.localhost;

    # PHP Native APP
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://php-native/;
    }

    # Laravel (APP v3)
    location /v3/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://laravel/;
    }
}
```

### Web Servers (Private Network)

**`php-native` Web Server**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  app.localhost;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/webapp/app;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   php56-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/webapp/app/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

**`laravel` Web Server**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  app.localhost;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/webapp/app-v3/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   php74-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/webapp/app-v3/public/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

***Thanks***

### Update

My question is: how to split the traffic, so any request pointed to `app.localhost` still forwarded to `php-native` web server and all request pointed to `app.localhost/v3` pointed to `laravel` web server ?

Comment: im unsure but what is the error or question that you may have? i dont see logs or issues.

Comment: It is your laravel app that should generate links to all the assets either using the `/v3` prefix or as the relative ones. You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62840133/7121513) answer (however every approach described there is just a better or worse workaround).

Comment: @djdomi i have updated my question. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm already found my solution.

### Step 1: Add `X-Frowarded-Prefix` to Front Proxy

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  app.localhost;

    # PHP Native APP
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://php-native/;
    }

    # Laravel (APP v3)
    location /v3/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix "/v3";
        proxy_pass http://laravel/;
    }
}
```

### Step2: Overide `getTrustedHeaderNames` function

```
protected function getTrustedHeaderNames()
{
    switch ($this->headers) {
        case 'HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB':
        case Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB:
            return Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB;

        case 'HEADER_FORWARDED':
        case Request::HEADER_FORWARDED:
            return Request::HEADER_FORWARDED;

        case 'HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR':
        case Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR:
            return Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR;

        case 'HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST':
        case Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST:
            return Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST;

        case 'HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT':
        case Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT:
            return Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT;

        case 'HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO':
        case Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO:
            return Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO;

        // add this to support x-forwarded-prefix
        case 'HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PREFIX':
        case Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PREFIX:
            return Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PREFIX;

        // add | Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PREFIX
        default:
            return Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR | Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST | Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT | Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO | Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB;
    }

    return $this->headers;
}
```

this is based on Symfony issu [symfony-issues-44572](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/44572)

Comment: not working, returned 500 error